# How to give feedback to uber driver through Uber API after ride is complete

Tags: uber-api

I am using the Uber API to book rides through my web app. I am using the REST SDK for everything and I cant seem to find any endpoint that lets you give a feedback the driver after the ride is complete. I initially thought the receipt endpoint has this functionality in it similar to how the actual Uber app does it. Can someone please point me to the REST SDK endpoint that lets you give a feedback to your driver. I am thinking of putting a star rating system along with a comment similar to Uber app. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. There is not a feedback endpoint, so you would not be able to put a rating system into your app. The users can rate their drivers from the summary email they get post trip, however.

We appreciate the feedback about wanting this endpoint however, and I've passed it along to the Uber API team.

Cheers.

Comment: ha ha ha :) looks like you manage everything from approving keys to replying on stackoverflow questions from uber's side, thank you for your answer kyle